# Hive column loading as null

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to load a table with 17 columns and one of the columns (a datetime) is getting loaded as null.  I'm not sure if I'm using the correct data type.   Here is my load script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
Weather(year INT, month INT, day int, TimeCST timestamp, temperature float,
dew float, humidity int, sea float, visibility int, wind STRING, wspeed float,
gust float, rain float, events string, conditions string, degrees int, dateutc datetime)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/home/ubuntu/final';
```

The troubling column is the dateutc column.  I've tried loading as both a datetime and a timestamp and both are showing up as null.  Here is a value from the underlying csv.  1/1/2000 7:53.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Try loading it as `string`. In your hive query, it can be used as `datetime/timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps in text files have to use the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. If they are in another format, declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.

On the table level, alternative timestamp formats can be supported by providing the format to the SerDe property "timestamp.formats" (as of release 1.2.0 with HIVE-9298). For example, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS,yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.

See this for the reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types